# How to merge two matrix with different size by values in R?

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I'm looking for ways to merge two matrix with differents size by merging those cells of column that have the same value.

For example the next two matrices:

Matrix 1:

```
a,  1  
b,  4  
c,  5
```

Matrix 2:

```
a,  8  
c,  9
```

After merging by first column:

```
a,  1,  8  
b,  4,  NA  
c,  5,  9
```

Thank you!

Comment: `merge(mat1,mat2,by="V1",all=TRUE)`

Comment: For data.frame, there is also `plyr::join` which mimics an sql call: `join(df1, df2, by = "ID")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'dimname' can be specified then `merge()` can be used easily.

```
mat1 <- matrix(c("a","b","c", 1,4,5), ncol=2,
               dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3"), c("id", "v1")))
mat2 <- matrix(c("a","c", 8, 9), ncol=2,
               dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("id", "v2")))

merge(mat1, mat2, by="id", all.x = TRUE)
  id v1   v2
1  a  1    8
2  b  4 <NA>
3  c  5    9
```

Row dimension names can be omitted as `dimnames = list(NULL, c("id", "v1"))`.

Comment: What if instead completing those rows that doesn't match with <NA> I want to delete the whole row?

Comment: Self response: Then "all.x" should be set to FALSE.

Comment: By default, 'all = FALSE' so that merge(mat1, mat2, by="id") should be enough. This is inner join or intersection of the by variable. On the other hand, all.x = TRUE is left outer join so that all values of x are preserved.